# How to dynamically set an include template

Tags: templating, include

I have a series of structure items, each with a product id, based on this id I would like to load in an additional template.

Something like this:

```
{% set embedAsset = entry.productId %}
{% include "embedAsset" %}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code should work if you remove the quotation marks enclosing your variable.

```
{% set embedAsset = entry.productId %}
{% include embedAsset %}
```

If you want, you can use string concatenation to add a path or extension to it.

```
{% set embedAsset = '_products/' ~ entry.productId ~ '.html' %}
{% include embedAsset %}
```

You could also add a "fallback template", that loads in case your dynamic template does not exist (read the [Twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html) for more info about this).

```
{% set embedAsset = '_products/' ~ entry.productId ~ '.html' %}
{% set defaultAsset = '_products/default.html' %}
{% include([embedAsset, defaultAsset]) %}
```

Comment: Belting! thank you very much for the super swift reply

Comment: @carlcs A variable should be in single parenthesis according [to Twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/include.html#include).

Comment: @DominikK interesting, it seems like this is new for Twig 2. See the [`include` tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/tags/include.html) documentation for Twig 1 in comparison.